# How would I create a button with an id in javascript

Tags: javascript

I was wondering how I would go about adding id's to buttons that I'[m creating in javascript. I am pretty much pulling whatever results match what I'm looking for from parse, and displaying it in an un-ordered list. Im bulding an invitation system so i have also created an accept button underneath. How do I go about associating the accept button with that specific object that was pulled?
Here is my code:

```
    function checkInvites(){
      var invite = Parse.Object.extend("sessions");
      var query = new Parse.Query(invite);
      query.equalTo("user", "bubbba");
      query.find({
        success: function(results) {
          console.log("Successfully retrieved " + results.length + " scores.");
           // Do something with the returned Parse.Object values
           for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
            var object = results[i];
            var items = document.getElementById("invites");
            var item = document.createElement("li");
            item.innerHTML = object.get('user')+' '+ object.id;
            items.appendChild(item);
            var btn = document.createElement("BUTTON");        // Create a <button> element
            var t = document.createTextNode("accept");       // Create a text node
            btn.appendChild(t);         // Append the text to <button>
            items.appendChild(btn);
          }
        },
        error: function(error) {
          alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
        }
      });
    }
```

Comment: The question is a fair one, but also consider whether you need an ID. IDs should only be used for elements that **will always be unique**. Even a "submit" button for a form might often have two copies - one at the top of a long page, one at the bottom. Both could be accessed easily using a class and JQuery.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use this:

```
var btn = document.createElement("BUTTON"); 
btn.id ='someId';
```

Please keep in mind that id should be an unique attribute, although you are not forced to make it unique. But if you don't plan to make it unique, better use a class.

---

If you are going to use [jQuery](http://jquery.com/), you could do this instead:

```
$('<button>accept</button>').attr('id', 'someId');
```

Explanation:

- `$('<button>accept</button>')`: creates an element as specified in string - a button with accept text
- `.attr('id', 'someId')`: set an attribute of element, this will add `id="someId"` to button
- resulting element's html looks like this: `<button id="someId">accept</button>`

Comment: I have never worked with jQuery before. Do you think you could explain some of the syntax? also is there an easier way to go about creating an invite system with parse?

Comment: I don't know parse api that much so I can't help with that, sorry. I will add explanation for my jquery code, but I would recommend you to learn it if you plan to write a lot of front-end code, it's a must and helps with productivity a lot.

Comment: Yea thanks! I will have to look into it

Answer (score 0):

An ID in javascript is just an attribute; when using jQuery you can just call `attr` function on the element or you can you build that function from scratch yourself

Comment: OP doesn't seem to be using jQuery.

Comment: That's true but the OP can use jQuery and what I suggested is a viable solution.

Comment: You could've at least provided an example on how to use it, not make them figure it all out.